# Cant connect port 9150 c++

Tags: c, port, tor

I am trying to connect to port 9150 on localhost ( TOR ) with this code:

```
WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2,0);
WSADATA wsaData;
if(WSAStartup(wVersionRequested,&wsaData) != 0)
{
    return 1;
}
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(fd < 0)
{
    printf("error 0");
}

struct sockaddr_in saddr;
saddr.sin_port = htons(9150);
saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
if(fd > 0)
{
    printf("error 1");
}
```

and its failing with "error 1". TOR/Vidalia is runing on this port and everything is ok, so erro must be in my code. Help me please.

Comment: What is the `if (fd > 0)` supposed to accomplish? Did you check the return code of `connect()`?

Comment: Yup that looks inverted

Comment: not only is it not inverted the connect is not going to affect the socket descriptor

Comment: There is no evidence here of a connect() failure, just a programming error. Your success test is wrong. BTW 'Error 1' is pretty useless. If you *do* get an error, and test for it correctly, use `perror()` or `strerror[]`: don't just make up your own meaningless error message.

Answer (score 1):

Minor things here:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror() */

WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2,0);
WSADATA wsaData;
if(WSAStartup(wVersionRequested,&wsaData) != 0)
{
    return 1;
}

int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int rv = 0;

if(fd < 0)
{
     perror("socket");
     exit(fd); /* or return */
}

struct sockaddr_in saddr;
saddr.sin_port = htons(9150);
saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

Your core problem is in the code below

```
rv = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
if(rv < 0)
{
     perror("connect");
     exit(rv); /* or return */
}
```